# how to scrape match info from sportstream365 using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape sportstream365.com for matches live broadcasts code.
here's my code.

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://sportstream365.com/')
print(r.text)
```

but match info is not in the source code retrieved from the site.

I think the site uses javascript to load the content dynamically, but I can't find the ajax request which loads the content. could someone help me ?
[image]

Comment: You need to check WebSocket (WS) tab to find information you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check WebSocket (WS) tab:
[image]

Comment: Right you are @gangabass, It is there. But how can i retrieve `the url` to that response visible within `frame` under `ws` tab? By default ***the url*** `ws://sportstream365.com/signcon?id=hPUVZhuKaRZ8oXuhy3-Jog` shows in its `header` tab within `ws` is of no use. Plus one for that invaluable info.